# How to connect to Redshift from AWS Glue (PySpark)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to connect to Redshift and run simple queries from a Glue DevEndpoint (that is requirement) but can not seems to connect.

Following code just times out:

```
df = spark.read \
  .format('jdbc') \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://my-redshift-cluster.c512345.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev?user=myuser&password=mypass") \
  .option("query", "select distinct(tablename) from pg_table_def where schemaname = 'public'; ") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://test") \
  .option("aws_iam_role", "arn:aws:iam::147912345678:role/my-glue-redshift-role") \
  .load()
```

What could be the reason?

I checked URL, user, password and also tried different IAM roles but every time just hangs..

Also tried without IAM role (just having URL, user/pass, schema/table that already exists there) and also hangs/timeout:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://my-redshift-cluster.c512345.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev") \
    .option("dbtable", "public.test") \
    .option("user", "myuser") \
    .option("password", "mypass") \
    .load()
```

Reading data (directly in Glue SSH terminal) from S3 or from Glue tables (catalog) seems fine so I know that Spark and Dataframes are fine, just there is something with connection to RedShift but not sure what?

Comment: do you have glue connection for it? you may have to create glue connection, test it and then add it to your glue job

Comment: I have a connector but how do you 'add it to a job'?

Comment: How about moving it to private subnet?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Create Glue Job]

Select last option while creating glue job. And in next screen, it will ask to select `Glue connection`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the correct path. I connect and  query  Redshift from  Glue PySpark job the same way except a minor change  of using

```
.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
```

I have also successfully used

```
.option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true")
```

instead of

```
.option("iam_role", "my_iam_role")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the time out error while trying to connect to RedShift from Glue.
Below are the changes which I made to connect to RedShift.

1. Made the RedShift publicly accessible. --> Navigate to redshift workspace and in data access section we need to enable the public option.
2. Add new inbound rule in the RedShift associated security group, selection Red Shift as type and I allowed all Ipv4 ip's based on my requirement.

With the above changed I was able to communicate with Red Shift Cluster.